# How is tracked data in an ORM kept up to date?

Tags: entity-framework, orm

How does something such as Entity Framework track changes to it's data when data changes could originate from other sources? For eg: When there is a cluster of the same asp net core app running and if one app updates a record but it's being tracked on a different instance and that instance receives a get request wouldn't it send out of date data?

Basically, how do ORMs preserve ACIDity if they perform local change tracking?

Comment: The simple (and only) answer is: not. EF does NOT track changes from other sources in any way. Nothing in the area is automated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to think of EF contexts and their local caching especially as short-lived. When you read an entity, that entity's "lifespan" should be thought of as matching the lifespan of the DbContext that originated it. Beyond that lifespan, the object is effectively just assumed to be like any other potentially stale copy of the data. Even within that lifespan it does not synchronize with the underlying data source, so the point of truth is when `SaveChanges` is called. The caching EF provides is more around the scenario of: "I'm going to load some entities, and those entities reference other entities. As the code iterates over the entities, when it comes across a reference to something else, EF will check to see if that something else has already been loaded and serve it before going to the DB." So in that sense, a long-lived DbContext is a bad thing because some of that cached data could be quite old and stale, and as the DbContext loads more data sifting through these tracked entities gets slower and the context consumes more memory.

In web applications, the DbContext is scoped typically to a single request, or shorter than that. (Unit of Work) This means that edits on concurrently handled requests aren't notified of each other's changes, and neither request sees changes made by other sources between the time those request contexts loaded their data and prepared to save. EF can be made aware of what to check for concurrent changes, normally a row version timestamp, and can block an update where this check fails. Beyond that, it is the developer that has to determine what action to take. This often means catching a concurrency fault and then handing off to an appropriate handler to log the details and notify the user. This could be a First-in-wins scenario where the user is notified that their changes failed and to try again; (with the refreshed data provided) A Last-in-wins scenario where the user is prompted that there have been changes but can overwrite; (and hopefully logged the event in case there are disputes/questions) Or a Merge where the system inspects the changes and provides details of any conflicts and changes for the user to review and adjust/accept/or cancel their update.

EF can help detect this, but ultimately the developer has to code for what to do about it.

In terms of detecting concurrent edits as they happen, that requires deliberate coding to do things like communicating changes between sessions (publish/subscribe) where each session listens for updates to entities it's actively working on, and broadcasting changes to entities as it updates them. To detect possible other changes to data by other sources means another process to listen for DB updates (beyond changes it already knows about made by the system) and broadcasting those change notifications to any active sessions.  Certainly a very cool thing to see working in action, but the cost & complexity that it introduces has to be justified beyond just handling concurrency issues on save. :)

Comment: Hmm... I don't see any justification of using a full ORM such as EF in my project in that case. Seems to me like the benefit lies in the ease of expressing business logic in an object oriented fashion which can be met by a micro-ORM such as Dapper while retaining the raw performance of the ADO.Net driver.